# Anaconda 3 on windows mixing out 32 and 64 bit versions?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda, x86-64

I have some issues with Anaconda3 on windows 10 64bit

Installing version Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64 and launching python on the command line (anaconda prompt) the following message appears :

```
    (base) C:\>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

It's actually a 64bit version but the message above displays " Anaconda, Inc. on win32". which is strange...

And then, when the ssl module is imported the following error appears :

```
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\u00178980\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 not a valid Win32 application.
```

It seems that there is some mixing out of 64 and 32 bit versions?